# Create public web URL link to specific section of Google Doc?

Tags: google-docs, google-apps

Suppose a Google Doc has been published on the web. When someone clicks on the public web URL, he is directed to the top of the page. Is it possible to have a URL that points to a specific section of the Google Doc?

It is preferred that the URL link is for viewing and not editing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes, it's possible by creating [bookmarks](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/45893?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

For this

- Click onto the desired section and go on `Insert -> Bookmark`
- The URL shown in the Url address bar will change to `https://docs.google.com/document/d/XXX/edit#bookmark=id.yyy`
- This is the bookmark URL that you can use to jump directly to the correct section of the document

Comment: Upvoted. But not exactly the answer I want. The bookmarked URL is a link for editing, not for viewing. It can be a problem if the Google Doc is set to editable mode for the public. Someone can accidentally edit the document. I will prefer to have a URL for viewing only.

Comment: This depends on your sharing settings. If the sharing settings under `Get link` is set to `Anyone on the internet with this link can view` no one apart from the owner will be able to edit the document apart from editors whom you specify under `Share with people and groups`.

Comment: You can probably change the url postfix from `/edit` to `/view` or `/preview` to do this; _preventing_ editing is in another castle, amongst the document settings.

Comment: @ti7,  I changed to `/view`, but there's no difference with `/edit` since the document can still be edited.

Comment: Why don't you change the sharing settings for the document?